# how to assign ajax variables for multiple buttons

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have an ajax code with php an SQL where I am trying to have three buttons change the name of a "scheduled" column depending on the value: yes (1) ,no (0),cancelled (2).

The scheduled button has data-target and data-role. once clicked, a modal appears containing three buttons (yes, no, cancelled) each with its own unique id to be used in ajax.

I have three functions each for the id names each also having a var of 0, 1 or 2.

The problem is that these variables do not trigger the update.

I simply have only 2 files: index.php for the main codes and connection.php for the database link and sql update.

table output
[image: table]

modal

[image: modal]

database (ajax_test)

[image: ajax_test]

index.php (table)

```
 <?php
        $table  = mysqli_query($connection ,'SELECT * FROM user');
        while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
              <td data-target="email"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>

              <td data-target="scheduled">

              <?php
                if ($row['scheduled'] == 1) {
               ?>

              <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">YES</a>

             <?php
               } else if ($row['scheduled'] == 0) {
               ?>

              <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">NO</a>

             <?php
           } else if ($row['scheduled'] == 2) {
               ?>

              <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">CANCELLED</a>

             <?php } ?> </td> </tr> <?php } ?>
```

index.php (modal popup)

```
    <!-- Modal-->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
         <a href="#" id="update_yes" class="btn btn-success text-center center-block">YES</a><br>
         <a href="#" id="update_no" class="btn btn-danger text-center center-block">NO</a><br>
         <a href="#" id="update_cancelled" class="btn btn-warning text-center center-block">CANCEL</a>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

index.php (ajax)

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
         var id  = $(this).data('id');
         var scheduled  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text();

         $('#scheduled').val(scheduled);
         $('#userId').val(id);
         $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
   });


 $('#update_no').click(function(){
    var id  = $('#userId').val();
    var scheduled = $('0').val();

    $.ajax({
        url      : 'connection.php',
        method   : 'post',
        data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
        success  : function(response){
                      // now update user record in table
                       $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text(scheduled);
                       $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                   }
    });
 });

 $('#update_yes').click(function(){
    var id  = $('#userId').val();
    var scheduled = $('1').val();

    $.ajax({
        url      : 'connection.php',
        method   : 'post',
        data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
        success  : function(response){
                      // now update user record in table
                       $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text(scheduled);
                       $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                   }
    });
 });

 $('#update_cancelled').click(function(){
    var id  = $('#userId').val();
    var scheduled = $('2').val();

    $.ajax({
        url      : 'connection.php',
        method   : 'post',
        data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
        success  : function(response){
                      // now update user record in table
                       $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text(scheduled);
                       $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                   } }); }); }); </script>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$connection =   mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'' ,'ajax_test');

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $scheduled = $_POST['scheduled'];

    $result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE user SET scheduled = '$scheduled' WHERE id='$id'");
}
?>
```

I would like to know what is wrong with the ajax functions, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your console, what errors are showing in your console?

Comment: $('#scheduled').val(scheduled);
$('#userId').val(id);                                                                                       These two lines need 'scheduled' and 'userId' elements and I couldn't find these as part of index.php. Are these elements part of index.php (which was not posted here)?

Comment: there are no errors in the console and the ajax is part of index.php

Comment: can you insert console.log( 'scheduled: ' + scheduled +', id:' + id ) before ajax call to see if those values are updated correctly? and again is there an element with id 'userId' ?

Comment: userId is for getting the unique id of a table row

Comment: yes. I could see the use of 'userId' variable. But, $('#userId').val(id) means you are assigning the value of variable 'id' to a HTML element 'userId' which should be present in index.php. Is that HTML present there? and can you insert 'console.log( 'scheduled: ' + scheduled +', id:' + id );' and remove $.ajax() call, and can you post the output of console.log here after inspecting the console?

Comment: index.php is also the html web page. also the console.log outputs "scheduled: undefined, id:undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191010/discussion-between-sabhari-karthik-and-button-press).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can simplify part of each of those to be simply

```
var scheduled = 0;
```

You are trying to get the id of the user by accessing them with:

```
var id  = $('#userId').val();
```

You are not showing any elements with the id="userId"

Instead use:

```
$(this).attr("data-id")
```

Once you get the data-id value and the value from the modal, you can make your ajax call with box values and pass it to connection to update the db record.